# Is it possible to replace html context menu with link context menu?

Tags: javascript, html, contextmenu

Im building a custom linkbox component, similar to the linkbox on this page: http://siteimprove-accessibility.net/Demo/Page/

Example Code:

```
export const Linkbox = ({}) => {
   const linkRef = useRef(null);

   return (
     // eslint-disable-next-line jsx-a11y/no-noninteractive-element-interactions
     <div
       role="region"
       tabIndex={0} // eslint-disable-line jsx-a11y/no-noninteractive-tabindex
       onKeyPress={(e) => {
         if (e.key === 'Enter') {
           linkRef.current.click();
         }
       }}
       onClick={() => {
       linkRef.current.click();
       }}
     >
     <div className="someClassName">
       <div role="heading">Title of the linkbox</div>
       <p>Main text of the linkbox</p>
       <a ref={linkRef} tabIndex={-1} href="https://google.com">
         Link to google
       </a>
     </div>
   </div>
  );
};
```

Now the problem with the linkbox here is that if I right click inside the linkbox, Im not given the default link context menu, which has the options like (open in a new tab, open in a new window, and copy link address). I want the default link context menu to be opened no matter where I right click inside the linkbox.

Im aware that this can be achieved by creating a linkbox by wrapping the whole content inside an anchor tag. But according to this a11y analysis, this strategy brings a11y problems:

https://saavutettavuusmalli.hel.fi/en/toteutus-ja-ohjelmistotestaus/link-box-pattern-notes-on-technical-implementation/

> In its typical implementation, a link box is challenging for screenreader users. Often, there is either a single link (anchor) tag which encompasses the entire box — rendering the box very difficult to navigate, comprehend, and interact with when using assistive technology

So is it possible to open the same context menu (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/contextmenu_event) that users get when they click a link? Like programmatically overwrite the one that is currently opening, and replace it with the context menu that pops up when users click a link?

EDIT: I do not wish to implement a whole custom context menu, since then I would have to deal with all language versions. I just would want to open the same context menu that opens when user clicks a link.

Comment: Please read the FAQ [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/215552). I don't see how we could help you from this question's text alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `contextmenu` event isn't triggered till after a `mouseup` event, you could on a `mousedown` event place a link element under the cursor's current position and when the user lets go of the right mouse the context menu for that link will appear.

```js
let link = document.createElement('a');
link.classList.add('contextlink');
//remove the link from the dom right after the contextmenu appears
link.addEventListener('contextmenu', () => {
  setTimeout(()=>link.remove(), 1)
});
document.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
  //flag to see if we right clicked in a box
  let inBox = e.target.classList.contains('box');
  //if it is the left mouse or not in the box
  //return right away
  if (e.button == 0 || !inBox) return;
  
  //change the href to one set in the element's data-* attribute
  link.href = '/' + e.target.dataset['link'];
  //position it so it is under the cursor
  link.style.left = (e.clientX - 5) + 'px';
  link.style.top = (e.clientY - 5) + 'px';
  //add it to the dom
  document.body.append(link);
})
```

```css
.boxes {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100px;
}

.box {
  flex:1 1 auto;
  height:100%;
  margin-right:10px;
  border:1px solid;
}

.contextlink {
  position: fixed;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box" data-link="test"></div>
  <div class="box" data-link="page2"></div>
  <div class="box" data-link="404"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tested the example, but could not get it working. Is it missing the contextLink?

Comment: Hmm, works for me on Windows and Linux versions of Chrome, Firefox, and Edge on Windows.  What are you testing on? Are you right clicking within bordered boxes?

Comment: My bad. I tried it with laptop touchpad, and therefore didn't work. With real mouse it seems to be working, thx. Though I would also need it to work on touchpad hmm

Comment: Touchpad or touchscreen? The pad should send the same event, touchscreens on the other hand uses the touch events (touchstart,touchend, etc). Add a log to the top of the mousedown event and see if it triggers for the right click, if it does then maybe it is sending `button` as 0 and triggering the if statement.

Comment: Touchpad. Though with touchpad, it will open the context menu as soon as you push it down. So not sure if the same strategy of putting anchor tag below it will work